# How to use azure APIM outside of vnet?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network

I have some azure functions running in a vnet and I just found out that the only way I can use azure APIM in a vnet is through the premium tier which is ridiculously expensive.
I was wondering if there is any way that I could have my APIM outside of Vnet and still be able to communicate with my services inside the vnet?

Comment: What do you mean  "some azure functions running in a vnet"? Do you deploy your Azure function integrated with a VNet like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet)?

Comment: well, I have all my services inside the app service environment such as cosmos DB and azure functions and I put that ASE inside the vnet.And no I'm not trying to do what the link you said is doing but I see that as an alternative if I cant get to APIM work with Vnet

Comment: If you have [External ASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-external-ase#:~:text=An%20External%20ASE%20has%20a%20public%20VIP,%20which,an%20ASE%20and%20an%20App%20Service%20plan%20together), then your API should access your azure function over the Internet?

Comment: Unfortunately, ASE costs about 1700$ and it is still too much for the application I'm trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

The only two SKUs supports VNET integration right now are Premium SKU and Developer SKU that has no SLA.

Please upvote the below features requests to bring the functionality to the other tiers
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/33997723-support-vnet-for-basic-tier-of-apim

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/33901033-provide-more-attractive-pricing